# Great variance in prediction quality using different trainings of the same LSTM on the same data

Tags: time-series, python, lstm, keras

I'm taking very first steps building a prediction model for time-series data using LSTM (and deep learning in general). A natural and motivating direction is stocks prices predictions.

## TL;DR

When training the *same* network multiple times on the *very same* input data I get extremely different prediction results. I understand and expect differences (due to different randomness), but I witness things like this:

[image: Nice predictions]

with with Mean absolute error: 3.95  /  Mean squared error: 30.39 vs.

[image: Not so nice predictions]

with with Mean absolute error: 19.07  /  Mean squared error: 637.35.

**Note** that these two are the results of two different runs of the same code given the same training data. See below more details.

## Questions

1. **Why?** What are the reason to witnessing such significant differences? One training round yields good predictions and the
   other one merely suggests that the model was able to learn something
   about the trends.
2. **What's next?** What should I do next? What terms should I focus on and study and investigate?

## More details

The code I'm using is mostly based on what I found in [how to develop lstm models for time series forecasting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) by Jason Brownlee.

### Steps

I started with 10 years of daily (adjusted) closing price of \$FB stock. I noticed the same behavior also with \$AMZN and other large cap stocks.

Next I build training chunks with 50 steps each.

```py
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
```

I kept 30% of the preprocessed data for validation. Lastly, I built the model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation=keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, verbose=1, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Complete notebook is available [here](https://gist.github.com/drorata/90f7ae87165afab948e248789feb8477). I will be happy to add more details in case you think I missed something and most importantly, I would love to get your feedback what should I investigate next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a well known issue. Keras/DL model training are not repeatable out of box. PS: Question maybe more suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Such differences in results is not very promising.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659482/why-cant-i-get-reproducible-results-in-keras-even-though-i-set-the-random-seeds

Comment: Thanks for the insightful link. However, it doesn't answer my question; *why* different random yield such tremendous differences? I obviously expect differences from different runs (that use different seeds), but in these examples it is as if the results are from completely different models. Moreover, the fact that in some cases the performance is good makes me wonder how to be more consistent. This is also the reason I thought this site is more appropriate than SO.

Comment: Indeed, puzzling.  It is more a modelling problem and suited here too, then. Some minor suggestions (1) One could run more training and see how performance fluctuates, if the range remains the same, then its model's behaviour. (2) Add Dropout layer and see if it prevents this fluctuation, looks like you added but commented out on GitHub.